# In Pokémon Go can the other IVs be in the same "range" as the "strongest" IV?

Tags: pokemon-go

When appraising a Pokémon, the team leader tells you which IV is the strongest. Then they give you a hint, as to what the value of the strongest IV is.

For example, if you're on team Valor, the leader might say "Its HP is its strongest feature.", followed by "its stats indicate that in battle, it'll get the job done.".  Which means that stamina is the highest IV, and it has a value of somewhere between 8 and 12.

Given that, can you assume that the other IV values are not within that same range, or just that they are lower than HP?

If stamina was 11. Could attack be 10, or does it have to be 7 or less?

Answer (score 2):

From the way the wording is written, it seems to indicate that unless two or three stats are listed, the top stat is ahead of the others by at least 1. [This site](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/appraisal/) supports this, saying that the stat named is the *best* stat. [GamePress](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-appraisal) agrees with this, as well.

> I see that its best attribute is its Attack **or** HP **or** Defense.
>
> *If a Pokémon's other stats are equal to its best stat, and then followed by...*
>
> It is matched equally by its Attack or HP or Defense.

Using your example, if you have a Pokémon with 11 STA, 10 ATK and DEF, your leader will indicate their strongest stat as STA and will give their second highest percentage quote. (as its IV perfection falls within 67-79%)